# how to build lc tool in linux?

Tags: compiling

lc----A tool to count lines of code in C files.

The make file of lc is given as below

```
SHELL=/bin/sh  
CC=cc

# Objects we link together.
OBJ=lc.o get.o

all:    $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o lc $(OBJ)

lc.o:   lc.c lc.h  
get.o:  get.c lc.h
```

I have the source on my desktop. So what should I enter on the shell command line. I have tried `/home/desktop/lc/lc.c`. It's not running.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing, but it sounds like you have source code files.  A `.c` file is meant for use by a compiler (like `gcc`) and not something that can be directly executed.

You need to compile them and then you'll get an executable, which is something you can run.

Try this:

- Open a terminal
- `cd` into the directory that has the make file
- `ls` and see if there is a `readme.txt` or a `docs` or `doc` directory.  Read any of those, or anything in those directories, it may give you specific instructions
- Failing that, try entering `make` and see what happens.  If it works you'll have an executable file called `lc` that you can run by entering `./lc`.

Comment: how to get .o object files from shell prompt

Comment: i have given  $ cc -o lc
and the output is /usr/ucb/cc:  language optional software package not installed

Comment: Your system is not set up as a development machine. You need to have a compiler to create executable code from the source code. Talk to your system administrator about getting you set up right.