# Can you explain me about following make file of "lc" tool

Tags: make

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to build lc tool in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12725/how-to-build-lc-tool-in-linux)

```
SHELL=/bin/sh  
CC=cc

# Objects we link together.
OBJ=lc.o get.o

all:    $(OBJ)  
    $(CC) -o lc   
          $(OBJ)

lc.o:   lc.c lc.h  
get.o:  get.c lc.h
```

Comment: Explain what? This is a simple makefile. Is there anything in particular you're stumbling on? If not, you should be reading a makefile tutorial.

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but there isn't an actual question here.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading a C programming tutorial like this
http://www.iu.hio.no/~mark/CTutorial/CTutorial.html

and reading the GNU make documentation
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/

Dup: [how to build lc tool in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12725/how-to-build-lc-tool-in-linux)